# SQL Server Compact 4.0 DateTime precision does not include seconds

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

According to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424.aspx SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 supports `DateTime` with the usual SQL Server precision (seconds and milliseconds to 3.33).

However I'm creating records using the SQL Server CE ADO.NET provider and `DateTime` but the data is only being stored to minute precision.

I've created SQL to return the data with `DataReader.GetDateTime(x)` and the value is being returned without seconds or milliseconds.

Does SQL Server Compact 4.0 actually support lower precision?

My DDL is:

```
CREATE TABLE [Message]
(
   [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
   [CreatedTimestamp] DATETIME NOT NULL,
   [ProcessedTimestamp] DATETIME NOT NULL,
   [QueueName] NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   [MessageType] NVARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
   [MessageContent] NTEXT NOT NULL,
   [MessageState] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

My code is:

```
using (SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
{
   connection.Open();

   using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand(
        "INSERT INTO Message " +
        "(Id, CreatedTimestamp, ProcessedTimestamp, QueueName, MessageType, MessageContent)" +
        "VALUES " +
        "(@Id, @CreatedTimestamp, @ProcessedTimestamp, @QueueName, @MessageType, @MessageContent)", connection))
   {
       command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@Id", message.MessageId) { DbType = DbType.Guid });
       command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@CreatedTimestamp", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")) { DbType = DbType.DateTime });
       command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@ProcessedTimestamp", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")) { DbType = DbType.DateTime });
       command.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@QueueName", queue) { DbType = DbType.String });

       //Code snipped...

       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you converting to string, then back to datetime?

Comment: Truthfully, that was a mistake. However I've changed the code to ...DateTime.UtcNow) { DbType = DbType.DateTime } and it doesn't seem to have made any difference

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The reason for me was in using SDF Viewer for exploring database. This application doesn't display seconds and milliseconds in datetime fields. But SQL Server Compact 4.0 actually stores datetime with high precision, as it's documented.

This question is old, but maybe my answer would be useful for someone.